# Sending Udp on port 8080?

Tags: networking, udp, network-protocols

Is it possible to send/receive udp over port 8080? Everything I see says 8080 is strictly a TCP port. I don't quite get why that would be?

Comment: Questions about networking are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 8080 is used by TCP or UDP. There is no restriction of Kernel for opening ports 8080 UDP. What happens is that there is a convention to use port 8080 as TCP, like squid proxy, but nothing prevents you from using UDP in it.